# How to set Timeout for Django Rest HTTP request

Tags: django, python-3.x, timeout, django-rest-framework

I am using Python 3.5, Django 1.9.5 and Django Rest Framework 3.3.3. I have only few POST apis in my server.

How can I set Timeout for each rest http request that if the execution for a request takes more then 3 minutes than it should return timeout in response and should stop execution of that request.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you will need to set this at the proxy/web server level.

With nginx you can use [`proxy_read_timeout`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_read_timeout):

```
proxy_read_timeout 180s;
```

Or you could set it at the application server level. Gunicorn has a [`timeout`](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/0.17.2/configure.html#timeout) setting.

Comment: I am using apache mod_wsgi server.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation. I'm sure there is a similar setting

Comment: Thanks Timmy :) I was not using any production server before, now I am using Gunicorn your solution worked.