# Rest Framework Image Validation

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a form that sends an image via Django Rest Framework. The serializer is as shown:

```
class AvatarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    avatar = Base64ImageField(validators=[image_validation])

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('avatar',)
```

I also have image validation that checks the size of the image so that it is not over 12MB:

```
def image_validation(image):
    # 12MB
    MAX_FILE_SIZE = 12000000
    print(image.name)
    if image.size > MAX_FILE_SIZE:
        print(image.size)
        raise ValidationError("File size too big!")
```

The image size gets printed out when I try to upload an image greater than 12mb, however, I get this response in Chrome's network tab: `Failed to load response data` I read that it might be because of the image's size (I was trying to upload a 30mb image). The `ValidationError` is not shown and the user gets a 500 server error. How can I fix this?

Comment: There is server timeout per request. If the request taking too much time it will kill and return 500 Internal Error before going into serializer.

Comment: @user2896120 are you using `django-extra-fields` for `Base64ImageField`?

Comment: @Mirza715 How do I make it so that if it takes too much time it returns a valid error?

Comment: @funnydman I am using `Base64ImageField`

Comment: @user2896120 see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42155616/how-to-set-timeout-for-django-rest-http-request . On the side note try to compress the files  before uploading it to server

Answer (score 6, accepted):

serializers has feature **field-level-validation** that validate the property before returns.

> https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation

```
class AvatarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    avatar = Base64ImageField()

    def validate_avatar(self, image):
        # 12MB
        MAX_FILE_SIZE = 12000000
        print(image.name)
        if image.size > MAX_FILE_SIZE:
            print(image.size)
            raise ValidationError("File size too big!")


    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('avatar',)
```

Comment: Can i know,  after usage of this, what error you are getting.

Comment: You need to return image in the validate_avatar func, unless you're going to get empty value for avatar field,

Comment: It seems `validate_avatar` should add a `return image`.